# How do buildings in (Tile based) city builders/colony sims keep track of each other?

Tags: architecture, movement, ai, path-finding, tiles

Like, how does a building in these games know if they're being powered? Or if they're within range of influence of a hospital or fire station, etc.

How would they know where to send an NPC or something to a particular building? Like, say a fire truck looking for a fire, or maybe a character in Rim World knowing where a crafting station is?

Comment: It is not very clear what is the issue you're facing. Are you assuming that those aspects are different in a tile based game w.r.t. a non tile based game?

Comment: You might be interested in [Will Wright's Dynamics for Designers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBcfiiulw-8).

Comment: I've linked this question to several past Q&A threads we have about efficiently updating connection and area of effect information for city-builder games. If you have a specific question not answered by this existing Q&A, or you encounter trouble adapting the existing answers to your needs, please edit your question to clarify what you need help with, and we can re-open it for new answers.